# UI design for Analytics / Big Data software products

Tags: user-interface, bigdata

I'm building a Big Data Project for my college final project. My back-end is ready, and now I need to focus on the UI development.

Since I'm no web expert, yet wanted to learn, I would ask this question.

**How do I learn about UI design for Analytics / Big Data software projects**.

I've googled various designs for the same, but didnt anything exciting.

Please provide your suggestions or point to a URL where I can have a look at the User interface of big data analytics products and then I can replicate that into my own project.

I known SO doesnt supports `discussion` questions, but I cannot find anywhere else, hence came over here.

Comment: I like the question, but i think its a better fit for UX stackoverflow?  http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ohh.... I was not aware of this site. Thanks.

Comment: Can you still provide your feedback on this. It will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: no idea friend but good luck on UX

Comment: Why close the question?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, we have slick yet powerful front-end frameworks available such as:

1. Twitter Bootstrap
2. Foundation (Zurb)
3. 99 Lime
4. Yahoo! Pure CSS
5. INK Interface Kit
6. Gumby

Out of these, i found **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)** as the most flexible framework that is easy to get started.

Well, if you are running out of time with UI Design for Analytics; you may consider getting ready-made templates on https://wrapbootstrap.com under *Admin and Dashboards* category and plug your back-end on the fly!

Hope this helps.

Comment: I like the wrapbootstrap site. I can easily steal the code from the firebug. ;) Thanks